# Why isn't my Babel-Loader converting my vendor code to be valid for IE8+?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, babel-loader, babel-polyfill

I'm using the latest Webpack, Babel and Babel-Loader in my Vue.js app.

I'm trying to have my code run on IE 8, 9 and 10 but it doesn't.

The problem is that IE10 and under complain that `const` is invalid syntax. I can see that this is coming from my `vendors~index.bundle.js` file. This file contains code that isn't mine.

In particular, I can see that the `const` is from a Vue addon that I'm using called [vue-snotify](https://github.com/artemsky/vue-snotify).

**Why isn't babel converting my vendor code to be valid for IE10 and under?**

## .babelrc

```
{
    "presets": [
        [
            "@babel/preset-env", {
                "useBuiltIns": "entry",
                "shippedProposals": true
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

## .browserslistrc

```
ie >= 8
```

## .webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path')
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin')
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    devtool: false,
    performance: {
        hints: false
    },
    entry: {
        index: './src/ui/index.js',
        style:'./src/ui/app.sass'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build/public/static'),
        filename: 'js/[name].bundle.js',
        chunkFilename: 'js/[name].bundle.js',
        publicPath: 'static/'
    },
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            chunks: 'all'
        }
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.m?js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                exclude: '/node_modules/',
                loader: 'vue-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.pug$/,
                loader: 'pug-plain-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.sass$/,
                use: [
                    'vue-style-loader',
                    'css-loader',
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',
                        options: {
                            indentedSyntax: true
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    name: '[hash].[ext]',
                    outputPath: 'assets/'
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
                use: 'url-loader?limit=10000'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new VueLoaderPlugin(),
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            { from: 'src/server/app', to: '../../app' },
            { from: 'src/server/public', to: '../' },
            { from: 'src/server/vendor', to: '../../vendor' }
        ])
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@components': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/ui/components'),
            '@store': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/ui/Store'),
            '@assets': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/ui/assets')
        },
        extensions: ['.js', '.vue']
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, package maintainers are encouraged to package sources that do not require additional transpilation steps or tooling to use. Babel enforces this by not transpiling modules that are under a `node_modules/` subpath (also to avoid introducing support or accidentally transpiling Babel-related sources).

This is not a working solution, but it should set you off in the right direction:

```
{
    test: /\.m?js$/,
    include: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),    // Include your sources.
      require.resolve('vue-snotify')     // Include `vue-snotify` main module.
    ],
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    options: {
        // Babel has it's own defaults, so these have to be edited as well.
        include: [
            require.resolve('vue-snotify')
        ]
    }
}
```

You can always debug Babel and get information on what sources it skipped transpiling because they matched ignore patterns by configuring [`debug`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug) when running:

```
DEBUG=babel* webpack
```

Given your setup right now, Babel should never receive a request for `vue-snotify` if you debugged. So first step would be to actually see that Babel is receiving a request to transpile `vue-snotify` and then further configure `babel-loader` to not ignore it's path.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar issue. [This](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/browser-compatibility.html#usebuiltins-usage) doc may be useful.

1. Since you're using `"useBuiltIns": "entry"` in your `presets`, try `import '@babel/polyfill'` in your entry file e.g. `main.js`. However, beware this may add unused polyfill and increase your bundle size.

> This will import ALL polyfills based on your browserslist targets so that you don't need to worry about dependency polyfills anymore, but will likely increase your final bundle size with some unused polyfills

OR

2. Try `useBuiltIns: "usage"` and specify missing polyfills, like so:

   `module.exports = {
       presets: [
           ['@vue/app', {
             useBuiltIns: "usage",
             polyfills: [
               "es6.promise",
               "es6.symbol"
            ]
           }]
         ]
   };`

OR

3. Try `useBuiltIns: "usage"`

> automatically detects the polyfills needed based on the language features used in your source code. This ensures only the minimum amount of polyfills are included in your final bundle. However, this also means **if one of your dependencies has specific requirements on polyfills, by default Babel won't be able to detect it.**

this is the one that got me. So if the dependency is written in an ES version that your target environments do not support, add that dependency to the `transpileDependencies` option in `vue.config.js`. So `vue.config.js` would have this

```
module.exports = {
  transpileDependencies: [
    "vue-snotify"
  ]
}
```

As for IE8, it is not supported AFAIK as per [vue github page](https://github.com/vuejs/vue#user-content-browser-compatibility)